# Search results while loop php

Tags: php, mysql, session, search, while-loop

So there's probably  a really simple way to sort this issue but at the moment I'm stumped for some reason. I'm working on a practice project, setting up a basic social network. I've created a basic php/ mysql search function for users to search for other users by querying the database, which functions like this:
1. User types in name of other user onto serach form on own profile page
2. This redirects them to a "search friends" php page which queries the database and locates similar records to the search. 
3. The page redirects to a results page, where the original user can see the mini profiles of the other users.

My issue is this: how to send the data produced from the while loop to the results page.

```
$resulting = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE LastName LIKE '%$secondquery%'
                            OR LastName LIKE '%$firstquery%'
                            OR LastName LIKE '%$thirdquery%'
                            OR LastName LIKE '%$fourthquery%'
                            OR FirstName LIKE '%$secondquery%'
                            OR FirstName LIKE '%$firstquery%'
                            OR FirstName LIKE '%$thirdquery%'
                            OR FirstName LIKE '%$fourthquery%'
                            ");
    $counting = mysqli_num_rows($resulting);
    if($counting != 0){

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resulting))
     {
         echo $row['FirstName'] . " " . $row['LastName'] . "<br>";

         }

         mysqli_close($con);
        header("location: results.php");
```

I thought about doing something like:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resulting))
     {
        if($n = 1){
         $_SESSION['a'] = $row['FirstName'] . " " . $row['LastName'] . "<br>";
         $n = 2;
        }elseif($n = 2){
        $_SESSION['b'] = $row['FirstName'] . " " . $row['LastName'] . "<br>";
        $n = 3;
        }
         }

         mysqli_close($con);
        header("location: results.php");
```

and then echoing the sessions on the results page but it relies too heavily on copy pasting etc. and I haven't got it working yet anyway. Anyone with any ideas on how best to approach this?

Grateful for any help!

Comment: Why do you want to redirect the user to results.php rather than just sending him/her the results?

Comment: in else if statements you must use == to compare $n against a value.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to share some data between your site pages, sessions are good choice, anyway, if the query result is too big, it may consume a lot of memory, so try to minimize data selection in your query. so may you want use something like change `$resulting` to `$_SESSION[resulting]` !

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it:

When the user clicks on search button the information the user typed into the search box is then sent to the results page through the url using a $_GET variable. Then the results page retrieves the $_GET variable and performs the query and displays the results.

Passing the search query through the URL is handy because then the user can navigate back to the results page through the browser history, or save bookmarks. This is similar to being able to copy and paste google search urls.

Hope this helps.